# DOM element disappearing immediately after update

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following javascript function that updates a text within a div when a button is clicked (using an onclick() event)
It works, but it immediately changes back to the old text.

```
function func()
{
    var text = document.getElementById("text");
    text.innerHTML = "Changed";
};
```

The HTML

```
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Text" onclick="func()"/>
    </form>
    <div id="text">
        Text to Change
    </div>
</body>
```

What am I missing? I also tried returning 'false' from the function but no luck.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are actually submitting the form. Prevent that by adding return false to the onclick attribute:

```
<input type="submit" value="Add Text" onclick="func(); return false;"/>
```

Comment: This works! Why does the 'return false' not work when it's in a function? Thanks!

Comment: @kassold you need to also do `return func()` as well as `return false;` in the function, but that's generally a much worse approach than doing addEventListener anyway.

Comment: What does the value false or true mean here?

Answer (score 5):

The form submits causing the page to refresh and reload the original content.

Try returning false on a form submit handler to prevent the default action:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
```

If I may suggest, avoid inline event handlers altogether. Instead use the modern events API with the much nicer `addEventListener`:

```
<body>
    <form id='mainForm'>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Text"/>
    </form>
    <div id="text">
        Text to Change
    </div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
var form = document.getElementById("mainForm");
var text = document.getElementById("text"); // probably not a very good id!
form.addEventListener("submit",function(e){ 
    text.innerHTML = "Hello!";
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: In fact, I tried that but it doesn't work. I will update my question.

Answer (score 1):

You are using input type="submit" inside Form tag , clicking this button will refresh the same page .

try

```
    <input type="button" value="Add Text" onclick="func()"/>

<div id="text">
    Text to Change
</div>
```

or remove form tag