# Dynamically-generated DOM elements disappearing immediately after form submission

Tags: javascript, html, electron

This is a follow-up question of the same old question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263414/dom-element-disappearing-immediately-after-update).

I am using `addEventListener` in an Electron app, I am wondering if there is a way to prevent the page being reloaded after each form submission?

In my code below, the `ipc.send` does something that triggers a reset to all DOM elements. I check that that the vanila JavaScript/HTML does work as expected. It is the `ipc` communication that clears the dynamically-generated DOMs.
Can this be circumvented in Electron?

`renderer.js`

```
const createCategoryButton = document.getElementById('create-category-button');
createCategoryButton.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  let newCategatoryName = document.getElementById('category-name-input').value;
  ipc.send("createCategoryButtonClicked", newCategatoryName);
})
```

More details on my `html` file:
`index.html`

```
<div id="new-menu-form-container">
        <form onsubmit="return false">
          <label id="category-label">Category Name</label>
          <input id="category-name-input" type="text" name="category-name">
          <button id="create-category-button">Create</button>
          <button id="delete-category-button">Delete</button>
          <br>
          <label id="item-label">Item Name</label>
          <input id="item-name-input" type="text" name="itemname">
          <button id="create-item-button">Create</button>
          <button id="delete-item-button">Delete</button>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: Do you actually want to submit the form, or just use the `<input>` as a button? There is always the possibility of adding the attribute `type="button"`...

Comment: One should note, that the default type of a `<button>` inside a form is `type="submit"`, so even when using a button you would need to specify its role appropriately.

Comment: @OskarGrosser I tried both ways: using <input> with ```type=button```, and using ```<button>```. Neither way works. I also tried adding this ```<form onSubmit=return false>```, also does not work. My form has a text field. Clicking the button submits that text value (and get stuff done with that value).

Comment: Could you provide some more code, perhaps some of your HTML as well? Now I see you are probably using Electron, but maybe you can make your [code be as minimal as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @TristanTran - not `<form onSubmit=return false>` you'd want `<form onsubmit="return false">`

Comment: @Bravo My typo in the comment. I did use exactly ```<form onsubmit="return false">```.

Comment: @TristanTran - well, that will definitely prevent the page reloading - the issue is soemthing else

Comment: @Bravo/Oskar, you are right. The issue is with Electron. When I remove the ```ipc.send``` line, all DOM remains present. Something in Electron must have reset the page. Updating my question.

Comment: Cannot seem to recreate your problem. `ipcRenderer.send()` works fine in my code, called in an event-listener of a `<button type="button">` inside a form.

Comment: @OskarGrosser This is my ```main.js``` side: ```ipcMain.on("createCategoryButtonClicked", (event, newCategoryName) => {
  database.insertCategory(newCategoryName);
  });```. This line, which modifies the database, causes the reset. I am going to dig into this further. Closing this question for now, since it has touched on a different issue.